# how to use batch file to open many batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I use `start.bat` to call multiple other batch files. I don't know how to do it right.

```
cd "C:\Users\server\Desktop\MAG8000_CSV\MAG8000_606402H016"
call mergingcsv.bat
```

I use this code and it works on my `start.bat`. It calls my `mergingcsv.bat`.

What do I need to call many `mergingcsv.bat`?

I need to open 41 `mergingcsv.bat` whereby each is in a separate folder.

When I do it like this

```
cd "C:\Users\server\Desktop\MAG8000_CSV\MAG8000_606402H016" 
call mergingcsv.bat   

cd "C:\Users\server\Desktop\MAG8000_CSV\MAG8000_606302H016" 
call mergingcsv2.bat

cd "C:\Users\server\Desktop\MAG8000_CSV\MAG8000_606202H016" 
call mergingcsv3.bat

cd "C:\Users\server\Desktop\MAG8000_CSV\MAG8000_606102H016" 
call mergingcsv4.bat
```

after the first call it pauses and I need to click to continue:

And how to make it automated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this commented batch code for `StartMergingCsv.bat`:

```
@echo off
rem Store full path of current directory on stack. Might be removed
rem if there is no need to restore the current directory after
rem processing all the batch files for merging CSV files.
pushd

rem For each subdirectory in C:\Users\server\Desktop\MAG8000_CSV
rem check if the subdirectory contains at least 1 mergingcsv*.bat.

rem If this condition is true, change the current directory to the
rem subdirectory containing the mergingcsv*.bat file(s) and call
rem each batch file matching this file name pattern.

for /D %%F in ("C:\Users\server\Desktop\MAG8000_CSV\*") do (
    if exist "%%F\mergingcsv*.bat" (
        cd /D "%%F"
        echo Merging CSV files in directory %%F ...
        for %%B in ("%%F\mergingcsv*.bat") do call "%%B"
    )
)

rem Restore initial current directory from stack. Might be removed, see above.
popd
```

Don't use `start.bat` as name for your batch file because **START** is a Windows standard command which you would replace by your batch file with name `start.bat`.

There should be no pause between each call of a batch file, except the `mergingcsv*.bat` contains a command like **PAUSE** which waits for a key press. `mergingcsv*.bat` should also not contain command **EXIT** without parameter `/B` as otherwise command processor would be exited and therefore there is no return to `StartMergingCsv.bat`.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `cd /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `pushd /?`
- `popd /?`
- `rem /?`

Run in command prompt window also:

- `exit /?`
- `pause /?`
- `start /?`

Comment: tnx sir mofi.. this helps me alot :)